# Use WaitForElement in aurelia-testing while running Karma in Internet Explorer

Tags: unit-testing, internet-explorer, karma-runner, aurelia

We are currently developing an Aurelia application that needs to run on Internet Explorer 11. Everything is great until we try to run our Karma/Tape tests on IE11 using karma-ie-launcher.

Karma start properly, some tests are executing, until a test using a `waitForDocumentElement` is encountered. Since `waitForDocumentElement` use promises, I told myself, great, I just need to load some `Promise` polyfills into Karma and everything will start working just like it does when using Chrome. But, It obviously didn't.

So, finally the question. Is there a way to have my tests running on Karma, targeting IE11 using `karma-ie-launcher` and have the ability to use `waitForDocumentElement` in my tests. It seems to be the culprit here since it use promises.

I may to build up a sample repo aside my project if its needed.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Here's the stack trace of the 'Out of stack space' error. For the records, rawValue is a bindable property I'm trying to assert inside a `waitForDocumentelement` so the binding and all have the time to do their stuff.

```
 WARN: 'Unhandled rejection TypeError: Unable to get property 'rawValue' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/_test/components/aurelia-numeric-input/aurelia-numeric-input.spec.js?ea0d4f3a76b6b818e30e08a7cbbc07dc5c11e02a:31:17)
   at r (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:31:9351)
   at i.prototype._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:14559)
   at i.prototype._settlePromise (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:15364)
   at i.prototype._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:16065)
   at i.prototype._settlePromises (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:17395)
   at r.prototype._drainQueue (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:29:3054)
   at r.prototype._drainQueues (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:29:3112)
   at drainQueues (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:29:1236)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:31140)'
WARN: 'Unhandled rejection TypeError: Unable to get property 'rawValue' of undefined or null reference
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:9876/base/dist/_test/components/aurelia-numeric-input/aurelia-numeric-input.spec.js?ea0d4f3a76b6b818e30e08a7cbbc07dc5c11e02a:36:17)
   at r (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:31:9351)
   at i.prototype._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:14559)
   at i.prototype._settlePromise (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:15364)
   at i.prototype._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:16065)
   at i.prototype._settlePromises (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:17395)
   at r.prototype._drainQueue (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:29:3054)
   at r.prototype._drainQueues (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:29:3112)
   at drainQueues (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:29:1236)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js?3d186ac6d244691754303d3153839bf42b57f7d1:30:31140)'
WARN: 'Unhandled rejection Error: Out of stack space
   at _compileElement (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2691:7)
   at _compileNode (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2547:11)
   at compile (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2516:7)
   at _compileElement (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2721:9)
   at _compileNode (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2547:11)
   at compile (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2516:7)
   at _compileElement (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2721:9)
   at _compileNode (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2547:11)
   at compile (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2516:7)
   at _compileElement (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating.js?1766dc2dd0fa5489caa6a2c286fad9ab686c2f09:2721:9)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Karma creates a property on the window named `__karma__` which lists the files that match the patterns in your karma.conf.js. Typically there's some code in your test entry point module that pares down this list of filenames and strips the extension, etc so they become a list of module names suitable for your loader... requirejs in your case ;)

This array of module names is then assigned to the `deps` property of the requirejs config which causes requirejs to load all of them before calling the function assigned to the `callback` property of the requirejs config.

I've been manually adding bluebird as the first dependency. Then in the callback, I do some feature detection and if Promise is not supported by the browser, assign it to window.Promise.

Here's an example that should map pretty cleanly to your setup. Relevant lines are indicated with comments.

```js
const testModules = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
    .filter(filename => /\.spec\.js$/.test(filename))
    .map(filename => filename.replace(/^\/base\/dist\/|\.js$/g, ''));

testModules.unshift('bluebird');  // make bluebird the first dependency in the array... this means it will be the first argument to the callback function (see below)

let karmaStarted = false;

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/base/global/output',
    paths: {
        'bluebird': '../some/path/to/bluebird.min' // ensure the loader can find bluebird
    },
    deps: testModules,  // bluebird is the first item in this array of modules
    callback: (bluebird: any) => {  // bluebird is the first arg... there are many other args but we don't care about the rest
        if (karmaStarted) {
            return;
        }

        // polyfill Promise on an as-needed basis.
        if (!('Promise' in window && 'resolve' in window.Promise && 'reject' in window.Promise && 'all' in window.Promise && 'race' in window.Promise)) {
            window.Promise = bluebird.Promise;
        }

        karmaStarted = true;
        window.__karma__.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks JD I'll have a look at it after lunch!

Comment: That helped a bit, but then I got some `Unhandled rejection Error: Out of stack space` errors in `aurelia-templating`. Also tests using waitForDocumentElement are still failing but at least I don't have the error about promises being rejected anymore. I started using waitForDocumentElement to test change on bindable properties of custom element.

Comment: Need the fetch polyfill too? Same technique

Comment: Include the stack trace, etc in the question

Comment: Done, as you can see, bluebird now seems to be loaded properly, there's just yet another things missing :) Maybe you're right for the fetch, especially if the templating use it.

Comment: Quick update, I resume working on that this afternoon and I'm still stuck at the `Unhandled rejection Error: Out of stack space`. I wonder if its not caused by some failed tests... I'm still ajusting some tests to work on IE, particularly those who play with the keyboard since the keyboard arrow definitions and some other keys differ on IE... (exemple ArrowUp is only UP and so on...)

Comment: Also found this bug on github, seems pretty much what I have here since i'm composing components. => https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/460

Comment: sounds similar- is the custom element doing anything with `<template>` or `document.createElement`

Comment: Mostly yes for the `<template>`. I have components that use other components inside them, so that mostly lead to having template inside template, which seems to be the issue here with IE.

Comment: apologies for the delay, I've added a possibe fix [here](https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/460#issuecomment-302878158)- could you please give it a try and let me know if it fixes the issue for you?